# WSO2 IS - Do a Single Logout using the IdentitySAMLSSOService

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I want to use the IdentitySAMLSSOService.wsdl to end a session using the doSingleLogout method but I can't find any documentation around. The method asks for a sessionId, the problem is that I don't know where to find that value, I've looking in the SAML Response, headers, etc.

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <xsd:doSingleLogout>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <xsd:sessionId></xsd:sessionId>
          </xsd:doSingleLogout>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

The ouput seems to be the same always with all the values I've tried.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:doSingleLogoutResponse xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2362:SAMLSSOReqValidationResponseDTO" xmlns:ax2360="http://base.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2362="http://dto.saml.sso.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax2364="http://util.java/xsd">
            <ax2362:assertionConsumerURL xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:destination xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:doSingleLogout>false</ax2362:doSingleLogout>
            <ax2362:forceAuthn>false</ax2362:forceAuthn>
            <ax2362:id xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:idPInitSSO>false</ax2362:idPInitSSO>
            <ax2362:issuer xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:logOutReq>true</ax2362:logOutReq>
            <ax2362:loginPageURL xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:logoutRespDTO xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:logoutResponse xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:passive>false</ax2362:passive>
            <ax2362:queryString xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:requestMessageString xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:response xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:rpSessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:subject xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2362:valid>false</ax2362:valid>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:doSingleLogoutResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using Identity Server 5.0.0 without SP1. The WebService is built into org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml (4.2.3) and it's exposed in identityserverurl:9443/services/IdentitySAMLSSOService?wsdl.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the execution flow, it can be any value.  As `doSingleLogout` method does not consider an actual SAML2 logout request, there is no any validate is happened according to the `sessionid` value.  However,  in real SSO signal logout flow,  sessionid would be the value of the 'samlssoTokenId' cookie which is set in to the browser.  Please note, `doSingleLogout`  method can not be used to send SAML logout request to other session participants. As i know, it can be used to destroy the SSO session in WSO2IS.

Also,  you can destroy the WSO2IS SSO session using following way by calling `commonauth` end point as mentioned in last selection in [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/08/openid-connect-identity-server/)

> https://localhost:9443/commonauth?commonAuthLogout=true&type=oidc2&sessionDataKey=7fa50562-2d0f-4234-8e39-8a7271b9b273&commonAuthCallerPath=http://localhost:8080/SSOWebApp/&relyingParty=SSOWebAPP